# How to compile swi-prolog from linux terminal along with query command?

Tags: command-line, prolog

In my abc.pl

```
test(ask, 'stack

overflow').
```

And when you run this on swi-prolog shell

```
?- test(ask, X).

X = 'stack\noverflow'
```

How can i run some command on Linux terminal to get the result like this

```
$`some command to compile and run abc.pl`

stack

overflow
```

#notice that `\n` is evaluated to `newline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$ swipl -g "consult(abc), test(ask, X), write(X), halt"
```

To learn more about SWI-Prolog command-line options, type:

```
$ man swipl
```